# Ошибка в коде Java

Tags: java

Есть такой код:

```
  class z{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

        try{
    String fileName = "file.txt";
    String text = "i";
    String delimiter = "p";
    Optional<String> result =
                   Files
                        .lines(Paths.get(fileName))
                        .filter(e -> e.contains(text))
                        .map(e -> {
                            int start = e.indexOf(text);
                            int end = e.indexOf(delimiter, start + text.length());

                            return e.substring(start, end);
                        })
                        .findFirst();

    result.ifPresent(System.out::println);

    }  catch(IOException e) { System.exit(0);  }  


    }
    }
```

Который выдает такую ошибку. Укажите на ошибку пожалуйста, я не понимаю в чем проблема

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at z.lambda$main$1(z.java:27)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at z.main(z.java:29)
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: если к длине строки прибавить любое положительное число отличное от 0, то всегда будет выход за длину строки.

Comment: эта программа ищет из текстового файла определенный фрагмент, и как избавится от этой ошибки??

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема в:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Что означает, что вы пытаетесь взять подстроку из строки используя индекс позиции в строке -1

Скорее всего это из-за того, что:

```
int start = e.indexOf(text);
```

возвращает -1 (не находит в строке искомую подстроку) и далее вы пытаетесь это применить в строке:

```
return e.substring(start, end);
```